# How to use "kubectl" command instead of "sudo kubectl"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

For every command with `kubectl` I need to use `sudo kubectl`.

I understand the security perspective but I am working on a test environment and I want to be able use it without `sudo`.

I tried to run `sudo -i` and use the root account to run`kubectl get pods`  but I received:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you
specify the right host or port?
```

I noticed that when I was playing with https://labs.play-with-k8s.com, the user is root and I can run `kubectl` freely.

I wanted to have the same thing on my Ubuntu machine with my Minikube.

When I run`kubectl get pods` with my regular account I received the error:

```
error: unable to read client-key /home/myuser/.minikube/client.key for minikube due to open /home/myuser/.minikube/client.key: permission denied
```

I supposed there are two ways:
1. Give everyone access to `/home/myuser/.minikube/`
2. Give my account permissions to run `kubectl` without `sudo`

EDIT:
Following @Konstantin Vustin request, here are the requested information:

```
myuser@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ ls -l  $(which kubectl)
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myuser myuser 54308597 Jun 13 05:21 /usr/local/bin/kubectl

myuser@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ ls -la ~ | grep kube
drwxr-xr-x  5 myuser myuser   4096 Jun 17 02:25 .kube
drwxrwxr-x 10 myuser myuser   4096 Jun 13 05:18 .minikube

myuser@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ ls -l ~/.kube
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 Jun 13 05:26 cache
-rw-------  1 myuser myuser 911 Jun 13 05:27 config
drwxrwxr-x  3 myuser myuser 4096 Jul 11 01:37 http-cache
```

Comment: could you show the output: `ls -l $(which kubectl)` and `ls -la ~ | grep kube` and `ls -l ~/.kube`?

Comment: I edited my answer with the requested information

Comment: and `ls -l /home/myuser/.minikube/`

Comment: Before you make any changes to your system, try running: " minikube kubectl get pods".  If it works, set the alias for kubectl to *minikube kubectl*

Comment: Another possible cause it that you're non-root user isn't allowed to run Docker commands.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Fix file permissions**

Most likely your kubectl files are not owned by your user.

You can set these permissions using below command.

```
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube
```

**Run kubectl with sudo**

Alternatively you can run kubectl as sudo user using a [persistent sudo shell](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.23/sudo.man.html#s).

```
sudo -s
```

then run your kubectl commands

```
kubectl get pods

kubectl describe <resource_type> <resource_name>
```

finally exit the sudo shell

```
exit
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion now and I still receives `permission denied`

Comment: Actually , no. Maybe because I run `chmod u+s kubectl` ?

Comment: OK, I change it back to the original permissions: `chmod 775 kubectl` and now it works with `sudo -s`. Great. This is what I wanted. thanks

Comment: Try reinstalling kubectl following [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/). Then try the answer again.

Comment: After `sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube` if you are still getting `permission denied` error, exit the shell, open a new terminal it should start working

Answer (score 13):

If anyone is wondering for k3s, use the following:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
```

After this, you can simply use `kubectl` rather than `sudo kubectl`.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) run `kubectl` with `sudo`.  `kubectl` doesn't need any special permissions, and is interacting entirely with a remote server over an HTTPS connection.  Kubernetes tends to take over the system it runs on, so even if you somehow were running `kubectl` against a local apiserver, being logged into the node at all would be odd and you could do the same level of administration remotely.

If you have been running it under `sudo`, it might have changed the ownership of some files to be inaccessible, and you can fix this (once) with

```
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube
```

(In your listing, `~/.kube/cache` is owned by root, not by myuser.)

Answer (score 6):

Ansible way to make `kubectl` able to run without `sudo`:

```
- name: Setup kubeconfig for user
  become: no
  command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - mkdir -p /home/$USER/.kube
    - sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /home/$USER/.kube/config
    - sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.kube/config
```

Or you could run this commands manually:

```
mkdir -p /home/$USER/.kube
cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /home/$USER/.kube/config
chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. It is suggested (by minikube) to change the ownership and permissions of ~/.kube and ~/.minikube after the installation.

```
sudo mv /root/.kube $HOME/.kube # this will write over any previous configuration
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube
sudo chgrp -R $USER $HOME/.kube

sudo mv /root/.minikube $HOME/.minikube # this will write over any previous configuration
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.minikube
sudo chgrp -R $USER $HOME/.minikube
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if proxy is set, if yes then set no_proxy for localhost and cluster server IP( which you can find in ~/.kube/config file **server: https://192.168.127.3:6443**)   in .bashrc or any other environment variable file.

```
no_proxy=localhost, 192.168.127.3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `kubeadm`, just follow the commands:

- Create `.kube` folde

  ```bash
  mkdir -p ~/.kube
  ```
- Copy `admin.conf` to this folder

  ```bash
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config
  ```
- Change owner of this file to ourselves

  ```bash
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) ~/.kube/config
  ```
- Now everything is good, and we don't have to use `sudo` or `--kubeconfig`

  ```bash
  kubectl get nodes
  ```

---

Source:

- [Certified Kubernetes Administrator](https://github.com/alifiroozi80/CKA/tree/main/CKA#configure-kubectl-command)

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to make an alias:

```bash
alias kubectl='sudo kubectl
```

Comment: like this one, clean and easy

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner on your installation

1. locate where this is installed
2. Change owner to your user
3. Test with version argument

```bash
# 1
$ whereis kubectl
kubectl: /usr/bin/kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
$ ll /usr/bin/kubectl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 45015040 Nov 10 10:51 /usr/bin/kubectl*
# 2
$ sudo chown $USER:$USER /usr/bin/kubectl
# 3
$ kubectl version --short
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.25.4
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
```

Answer (score 0):

For Accessing K3S custer without sudo...

```
export KUBECONFIG="~/.kube/config:/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml"

sudo chmod u+s /var/lib/rancher/k3s/data/current/bin/kubectl
```

Answer (score -4):

Try setuid:

```
chmod u+s kubectl
```

The keys can be read by kubectl, while not open to everyone.

Comment: I did it, it changed the `kubectl` permissions from `-rwxrwxr-x` to `-rwsrwxr-x` but I am still getting error `permission denied` when running `kubectl get pods`

Comment: kubectl should be owned by root

Comment: @KunLi where this requirement is documented?

Comment: Making random binaries setuid root isn't actually a good idea.  In the case of `kubectl`, I could use an intermediate configmap to read arbitrary files off the local host, which would be bad.